# How to use flash to create a GUI for a text-based python game?

Tags: python, flash, user-interface, integrate

We have a text-based python game (without using pygame) and we would like to give it a GUI. The idea would be to have a background layer image (like a tavern or a shop) and other layers of images on top of it (e.g. characters appearing). The other thing we need is to have an integrated text box for information display and a way to choose what you want to do next (Do you want to go to the forest? (y/n)).

Is there a good way to accomplish these goals in flash?

If not, then what should we do?

Comment: Depends a lot on how reusable the code in the text-based game works. You'll have to restructure *a bit* anyway if you want such tight integration, but it's very easy (especially for beginners) to write code such that it essentially has to be rewritten entirely to allow things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [pyjs](http://pyjs.org). It lets you write JavaScript-powered web applications entirely in Python. For your requirement specification it would be a viable platform.